# Measure polyline length in QGIS

Tags: polygon, line, measurements, qgis-2.12

I try to measure the length (in meters) of the polyline layer that pass inside the olive polygon layer only, and if it possible export the wanted polyline into new layer:

[image]

the attribute table of the polyline is:

[image]

All the layers as the same CRS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do an intersect of the line with the polygon layer. Then calculate the length of all the segments and sum them.